# Implement MVP for passing data from network to listviews

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, design-patterns, mvp

I want to implement a MVP pattern for the following:
My view is a list fragment displaying a list.
My model is the data to be displayed to the list that come from network calls.
My controller is the one passing the data between view and model.
My flow is:
1) I do a network request and get back a response that I show ~20 items. Each item has a list of URLs of items (~70).
2) On click of an item I go in a loop and pass to a volley queue requests for each of these URLs (so essentially) ~70 volley requests as submitted one after the other. As I get each response I update my adapter.

Question:
How can I convert (2) so that I use the MVP and update the view via some kind of callback mechanism? I assume it is not a good idea to callback for each one of this responses and call `onNotifyDataSetChanged()` 70 times
What is the best practice for this?

**More context bellow**

I have an app that is composed of 2 list fragments and 1 simple fragment with a layout view.
First list fragment shows a list of ~20 items.
Each item when clicked results in a network call that brings from a server ~70 items (max) that are displayed in another list in the second list fragment.
Once the user clicks in the list item data specific to that item are fetched from network and displayed in the last fragment.
So basically the first list is "broken" down to data. But the items in the second list are not more than ~70.

Design:
I have used volley queue for the network calls and functionality-wise it works fine and I display the data I need fine.
I have added a listener to the volley request and from my listener I update my adapter(s).
The benefit is that as response come I display them by notifying my adapter so the user doesn't have to wait for all the 70 requests to complete before seeing data.

**Problem:**
Due to the fact that on click of the first fragment as I move to the second I start these backend calls and as I go to the third these calls are queued (I can see it in the logs), if I go to the third fragment the calls for the rest of the items are kept on firing and same if I go back to first.
Due to the fact that I get the responses for these requests from the Volley within the adapters and the actual fragment might not be "relevant" anymore, how can I design this better?
I guess some kind of model-view pattern but in my case I don't want to wait for all network calls to finish to get the data from my model (preferably)

Comment: How can I improve this post? Can someone tell me if my post is not very helpful or what I am describing is not a common problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same design you have now and just add tags to the requests you make for one fragment:

```
request.setTag("fragX");
```

then when you hide/remove the fragment you can do:

```
getRequestQueue().cancelAll("fragX");
```

This will prevent you from receiving "fragX" responses from the once that have been enqueued.

You can also filer the responses you receive and go even further and use RxJava so you can work with streams and apart from filtering perform various other handy operations on the responses.

I use [jus](https://github.com/apptik/jus) which started as fork of Volley but now supports many options including RxJava. You can examples and volley migration samples there also.